# Active Record Query don't load all id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an active record query like this one:

```
House.where.not(id: Person.ill.pluck(:house_id))
```

When I run `explain` on this query, I see that all the id's get loaded into the query:

```
Seq Scan on houses  (cost=0.00..4274.07 rows=1102 width=77)
 Filter: id <> ALL ('{1117,487,842,126,127,459,458,515,332,55,54,10,1697,449,448,1555,13,510,1986,8,9,7,6,5,1865,519,157,513,512,56,103,28,27,97,25,23,385,138,278,92,1,435,196,195,61,363,229,230,238,237,231,160,158,749,748,518,517,174,173,172,395,153,1170,207,206,276,199,198, ....
```

Is there a more performent method to achieve the same query? Without loading all the ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pluck` runs its query immediately, because it returns an array of IDs.

You can use `select` to keep the result as a Relation, which will then be used in-place as a subquery:

```
House.where.not(id: Person.ill.select(:house_id))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [SQL JOIN](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins), but you will cannot reuse `ill` scope here. If for example, this scope looks like this:

```
scope :ill, -> { where(status: 'ill') }
```

then your query could be like this:

```
House.joins("JOIN persons ON houses.id = persons.house_id AND persons.status <> 'ill'")
```

Comment: Nice - worth referencing the ActiveRecord syntax for this too: `House.joins(:persons).where.not(persons: { status: 'ill' })`.

Comment: @SRack your example will be slower because it will join ALL persons and then filter them in `WHERE` clause. My example will join only `persons` with `status: 'ill'`.